# Как правильно удалить старые записи из partitions

Tags: mysql, sql

Хочу почистить старые данные которым уже более 3-x лет из PARTITIONS. При таком запросе:

```js
EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT *
FROM post
```

Я получил это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Верно ли будет использовать такой запрос для удаления?
`ALTER TABLE post DROP PARTITION y2013m8, y2013m9, y2013m10...` и так далее;

И как посмотреть весь список значений из колонки partitions?

Comment: [Obtaining Information About Partitions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-info.html)

Comment: *Верно ли будет использовать такой запрос для удаления?* Зависит от типа партиционирования. Для RANGE/LIST - да. Для HASH/KEY - нет. См. [ALTER TABLE Partition Operations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table-partition-operations.html).

Comment: @Akina, по этой ссылке нет ничего про удаление или просмотр всех значений из колонки partitions. Если пользуетесь phpMyAdmin можно после выполненного запроса нажать параметры - полные тесты - ок. И вуаля, все значения из всех столбцов будут полными.

Comment: @Akina, как узнать тип партиционирования?

Comment: *по этой ссылке нет ничего про удаление или просмотр всех значений из колонки partitions.* Да, там по ссылкам не выводится информация о Ваших партициях. То, что по ссылке, нужно прочитать, понять, и использовать на практике. *как узнать тип партиционирования?* Это описано в первой из ссылок.